# Exception on nested style wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

This is my style inside `Grid.Resources`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
    <Grid>
         .....
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         .....
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" ....... />
    .....
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ToggleButtonControlTemplate}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SidePanel" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Resources>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PreviewSidePanelToggleButtonStyle" /> ---> Exception
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

With this design but UI looks good in design mode. But when I run this application I get an exception in the line:

```
<StaticResource ResourceKey="PreviewSidePanelToggleButtonStyle" />
```

with the message: "Set property 'System.Windows.Style.Resources' threw an exception".

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you don't have any code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception is because you are trying to assign Style to Resources . Resource property is of Type ResourceDictionary and your is of type Style so casting is not possible and Exception is thrown .I dont know why you doing this but why so ever you doing this it is incorrect you can access the PreviewSidePanelToggleButtonStyle directly instead of forwarding it to Style resources. [Read remark section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You are right. I had a set of ToggleButton which was inside of a StackPanel; so instead of assigning Style to all the buttons separately I wanted to apply the style to the parent. But after I saw the innerexception (which I didn't earlier) and reading your explanation I know what went wrong. Thanks a lot. I just put all the style inside Style.Resources instead making a reference to it.

Comment: but that doesn't explain why it was working in design mode tho. any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to redefine style in your resource section. In case you want to do that, use **`StaticResourceExtension`** and also you have to set **`x:Key`** for any item declared under resources section.

This should work:

```
<StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="PreviewSidePanelToggleButtonStyle"
                         x:Key="SomeKey"/>
```